# Why do the dogs pet the characters in Nichijou?

Tags: nichijou

I have seen this scene where it's only Yukko who's laying on the ground and they just like petting the *Nichijou* character just like that, but the one who did that in the different scene is just only the big dog.

What's the reason these two dogs doing this? And, why a dog?

[image: the dogs petting the characters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up that video by googling the title, and the answer appears right next: Grandpa appears and does the same hand gesture as the dogs are doing with their paws − touches "Takashi" on the shoulder. Grandpa then explains that humans console each other, and dogs do the same thing.

Comment: but it still confusing me... i mean.. what ?

Comment: it's a comedy gag anime, it's supposed to be at least slightly confusing

Comment: is that so... okay...

Comment: Not to sound like a robot, but confusion is one of the popular comedic devices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comedic_device). Look up "confusion in comedy" sometime if you genuinely don't understand.