# What is this dance that characters in Nichijou do during the episode breaks?

Tags: nichijou

I always seen this kind of clip in every of Nichijou episode (but with different movement). You can see them doing that on this [Scene](https://youtu.be/pVbCCHbYGNw?t=2m24s)

Is this just some random movement?

[image]

Comment: Hey! I'd consider making your title (for this and [the other recently asked Nichijou question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/42765/49)) a bit more descriptive, since they're not likely to help anyone else in their current form — it seems highly unlikely that someone with the exact same question would ever be able to get here with the current title and description.

Comment: thanks @JNat, i dont know  how to describe it with my bad grammar and english...

Comment: Well, I didn't watch any of the scenes myself, so I lack some context on the actions and all that. But what about something like: "Why do Nichijou characters cross theirs arms in front of their chests?" or something similar? All in all, and even with bad grammar, just be more descriptive — the community will fix typos and the like themselves ;)

Comment: Can you suggest me the appropriate title for the other recently question that I posted before?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it's just an original dancing choreography designed to look endearing, cute and fun. Kids on the streets don't usually perform a dance while playing rock-paper-scissors (or jan-ken-pon).

Comment: kids probably not dance but they sometime sing and do some synchronize movement with their partner while playing janken (which probably count as dancing as well)